# AWS: Amazon API Gateway Unknown Endpoint Error upon Testing Deployed API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

We have an API that we would like to try connecting with the Amazon API Gateway. I've been trying some very basic calls, but to no avail. For example, if we don't pass any authentication data in the query strings during the `GET` call using Postman:

```
GET https://<host>/<resource>
```

Then I correctly receive an error message:

```
{
"error": "Invalid authentication key",
"errorcode": 0
}
```

In the Gateway I have the following settings for the method:

- `Method Request`

  - No Authorization, API Key not required
  - Some query string parameters which are not being set in either Postman or the API Gateway call
  - No request headers
  - no request models
- `Integration Request`

  - HTTP Proxy Integration type, GET
  - Endpoint URl is the same URL I call using Postman above
  - No parameter, header or body mappings
- `Integration Response`

  - Single `200 OK` passthrough
- `Method response`

  - Various HTTP Statuses
  - Response model as per our API's Swagger definition

All other methods have `mock integration`. Calling the method via Postman at our backend domain works as intended (i.e. gives the error message above).

Calling the deployed API Gateway method, however, results in:

- `"message": "Unknown endpoint error."` if done using the `Method Test` in the API Gateway
- `"message": "Internal server error"`, if called from the browser or Postman.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

EDIT: I just noticed that one of the response headers that are set when using Postman or Browser is:

`X-Cache: Error from cloudfront`

The docs says that this errror is set [if the origin server returns an expired certificate, an invalid certificate or a self-signed certificate, or if the origin server returns the certificate chain in the wrong order](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html), but our certificate is valid and I cannot note and problems with the certificate chain...